# Continuity of piecewise $f$ and its partials, $f(x,y)= \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ for $x,y\neq 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $$f(x,y) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       0, & (x,y)=0 \\
>       \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}, & (x,y) \neq0 \\
> \end{array} 
> \right.$$ Determine if $f, \partial_xf$ and $\partial_yf$ are continuous.

So in $\mathbb{R^2}_{\ne 0}$ we have that $f$ is a rational function hence continuous. For the case $(x,y) = 0$ I managed to get the following:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ $$|f(x,y)-f(0)|=\left|\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leqslant \frac{|xy||(x^2+y^2)|}{x^2+y^2} = |xy| = (xy)^2 < \varepsilon$$ when $xy < \sqrt{\varepsilon.}$

However for $ \partial_xf = \frac{y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ I cannot seem to be able to get anything. Also I'm not sure does the fact this is also a rational function imply continuity at $\mathbb{R^2}_{\ne 0}$?

Comment: Like you say, there is no doubt about continuity in the region $\mathbb R^2_{\neq 0}$ because the functions are all rational functions which are non-vanishing expect at $0$. The only doubt is at zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Transform the partial derivatives via polar coordinates. Also there's an error in your  partial derivative w.r.t. $x$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^{\color{red}4})}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{r^5(\cos^4\theta+4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta-\sin^4\theta)}{r^4}=r(\cos2\theta+\sin^22\theta),$$
therefor it clearly tends to $0$, and similarly for the other partial derivative.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out!